# Can we call the push notification enrollment apis directly without the SDK?

Tags: mobilepush

Can we change the push notification enrollment urls being invoked from the sales force SDK? Also what are the challenges on invoking the salesforce enrollment apis explicitly, without using the SDK?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about the Marketing Cloud SDKs:

1. You can definitely call the device registration routes without using the SDK.
2. For starters you'd have no guarantee that those routes won't change and affect your application(s) as the routes are not part of a publicly documented API.  Other challenges?  It really just depends on your use cases.  The safest bet is to use the SDKs.

Other Salesforce SDKs?  They'd have to chime in independently.